# How can I read a file from android internal storage and provide it as input to a method

Tags: android, file

Displaying the File path in the textview & Toast:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

    assert data != null;
    textView.setText(data.getDataString());

    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), data.getDataString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I want to select a file from my phone and then give it as input to a method.
How to get the path of the file in android studio?
I have used this code in eclipse and it works when I give the file path manually:

```
public static void Encrypt(String path) throws Exception{



        // file to be encrypted
        FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream(path);

        // encrypted file
        FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream("encryptedfile.des");

        // password to encrypt the file
        String password = "password";

        byte[] salt = new byte[8];
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        secureRandom.nextBytes(salt);
        FileOutputStream saltOutFile = new FileOutputStream("salt.enc");
        saltOutFile.write(salt);
        saltOutFile.close();

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory
                .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536,
                256);
        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

        //
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
        AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();

      
        FileOutputStream ivOutFile = new FileOutputStream("iv.enc");
        byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        ivOutFile.write(iv);
        ivOutFile.close();

        //file encryption
        byte[] input = new byte[64];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = inFile.read(input)) != -1) {
            byte[] output = cipher.update(input, 0, bytesRead);
            if (output != null)
                outFile.write(output);
        }

        byte[] output = cipher.doFinal();
        if (output != null)
            outFile.write(output);

        inFile.close();
        outFile.flush();
        outFile.close();


    }
```

I want to give the path of the file to the fileinputstream above. How can i do that?

The following is the mainactivity class where the encryption method is called, its connected to button encrypt:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public static TextView textView,message;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    message = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
}

public void BrowseButton(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    assert data != null;
    textView.setText(data.getDataString());
    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), data.getDataString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public void Encrypt(View view) throws Exception {
    Encryption.Encrypt();
}

public void Decrypt(View view) throws Exception{
    Decryption.Decrypt();
}
```

}

I made the following changes to the Encryption call :

```
 public void Encrypt(View view) throws Exception {
    String path= String.valueOf(textView);
    Encryption.Encrypt(path);
}
```

The textView displays the path of the file browsed by the user.
Erorrs:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Comment: Well has the method such a 'path' parameter? Or what is the problem?

Comment: Yes i am using the following :FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream("path"));               When i run this code in eclipse and give the exact path of the file i want to use the method runs fine but i dont know how to do that in android. The app just crashes when i try to run this method.

Comment: I did. Can you please help

Comment: `I want to give the path of the file to the fileinputstream above. How can i do that?` I do not understand the question. Its new FileInputStream(path) as you already know. (although you use only a file name. That will not work. You have to use a full path). Further i see no method that takes a path. (And you continue to talk about a method.)

Comment: I posted the whole method(Encrypt method). I want the user to select the file they want to encrypt. I tried giving the full path but the app just crashes.

Comment: The Encrypt method has no parameter that takes a path. Give it a path parameter to begin with. And show the code where you call that method so we clearly see what 'path' you use.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I posted my mainclass where the encryption method is called.     Can you please show me how to make that parameter which takes the path.

Comment: You call it without a path parameter. So how should that work? We wanna see it like Encryption.Encrypt(path); And we wanna see the path variable. We wanna know what you use as path.

Comment: I made the path variable and i posted the code above. Its still not working.

Comment: `String path= String.valueOf(textView);` ? My god.. How would we know which path you use? What is the value of path? Toast or log it it to see and tell us! And 'not working' is a very poor problem description. Errors? Exceptions? Why do you take so much time to give rekevant info?

Comment: I posted everything. There is a toast to show the path. And i also described the error.U missed it.

Comment: You see the toast. We dont. So tell what you see. `Encryption.Encryptt(path);` does not match `public static void Encrypt() throws Exception` as there is no path parameter. Nor can we see where you use it. Nor did you tell what not working means. `(No such file or directory).` Well which file? Tell us complete path. Adapt your code so we see that you use the path you are talking about. Give your function a path parameter.

Comment: Toast is at the top. I forgot to edit the path parameter.

Comment: You better put a Toast for path in Encrypt(String path) as there is where you use it. Further you still did not tell what the value for path is that you see -or what is displayed- in that Toast nor did you tell what goes wrong.